# EJS is secure to use? (Embedded JS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm rendering some sensitive datas with `EJS`. Anybody can see it in development console of browsers like this : ?

```
console.log(ejs.render(..));
```

Comment: node.js executes on the server. unless you're doing some processing on the client, there's no way someone could use their client-side console to see what's going on with the server.

Comment: I'm rendering user's secret data too, I just wanted to be sure. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

You've said you're rendering the secret information. That being the case, your rendering technology has nothing to do with it. If the page is delivered securely (SSL, etc.), then you should be fine. If it isn't, it's not secure whether you use ejs or not.